# Subject doesn't emit data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an app which receives data from user and validate them in the form. When validation is true button is getting enabled and user is getting permitted to submit his order in this scenario.

I don't know why in this component my subjects don't work. I mean I can `.next(value)` in a component and in service I can `console.log(value)` to check its getting arrived to service or not.

I can see that in service is getting received but ,that received value isn't being subscribed in the component I want to use them. I stopped running projects but couldn't be fixed. Here is what I tried:

**AuthService.ts**

```
  emailSubject=new Subject<string>();
  getEmail(value)
  {
    console.log(value);
    this.emailSubject.next(value); //prints email to the console correctly
  }
```

**CarService.ts**

```
export class CarService
{
    carrierSubject=new Subject<number>();
    orderSubject=new Subject<Order[]>();
    totalCostSubject=new Subject<number>();
    lastTotalCostSubject=new Subject<number>();
  getId(myIndex:number)
   {
    this.carrierSubject.next(myIndex);
   }
 setOrders(value)
   {
     console.log(value);
     this.orderSubject.next(value);
   }
  setTotalCost(value)
   {
     this.totalCostSubject.next(value);
   }
   lastSetTotalCost(value)
   {
     this.lastTotalCostSubject.next(value);
   }
```

**CarPayment.ts**

```
export class CarPaymentComponent implements OnInit {
  car:Car; 
  selectedCar:string;
  somePlaceholder : number = 0;
  myArray:Order[];
  email:string;
  constructor(private carService:CarService,private authService:AuthService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.carService.carrierSubject.subscribe(value=>
      {  
         this.car=this.carService.getCar(value);
         this.selectedCar=this.car.brand;
      });
      this.carService.lastTotalCostSubject.subscribe(value=>
        {  
         this.somePlaceholder=value;
        });
        this.carService.orderSubject.subscribe(value=>
          { 
            this.myArray=value;
          }
          );
        this.authService.emailSubject.subscribe(value=>
          {
            this.email=value;
          });
    }
    onSubmit()
    {
      console.log("ORDER INFO")
      console.log('This order ordered by:'+this.email);
      console.log("Ordered Car:"+this.selectedCar);
      console.log("Ordered Parts:"+this.myArray);
      console.log("Total Cost:"+this.somePlaceholder);
    }
}
```

Comment: if you never call any of the `set`er methods in the service (the ones with the `next` in their logic) there won't be any value emitted.

Comment: If you want to receive the current value of the subjects when new subscriptions are performed use `BehaviorSubject` instead of `Subject`

Comment: you next the data before subscribe it, and when you subscribe it there is no available data, for solving this you should use BehaviorSubject or ReplySubject(1).

Comment: Can you give me an example?I don't know how to define behaviorSubject in the service.I've never used before and that expects an arguement from me so what should I pass in this behavior subject?

Comment: For example I succeded to get Email by behavior subject (   emailSubject=new BehaviorSubject<string>("");)  . What about the others?They gave me error(brand undefined)

Answer (score 2):

As @lealceldeiro and @FatemeFazli have mentioned, you'd need to use `BehaviorSubject` or `ReplaySubject`. The reason you code is not working is because your observables haven't fired any value yet. Essentially, when you do `.subscribe`, you are hooking into change event. But in your case, the change hasn't been fired yet.

**AuthService.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs'; //<----Add this line

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  emailSubject = new BehaviorSubject<string>("test@test.com"); //<--- provide an initial value here
  getEmail(value) {
    console.log(value);
    this.emailSubject.next(value); //prints email to the console correctly
  }
}
```

**CarService.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class CarService {
  carrierSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0); //<-- provide an initial value here
  orderSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Order[]>([]); //<-- provide an initial value here
  totalCostSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0); //<-- provide an initial value here
  lastTotalCostSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0); //<-- provide an initial value here

  getId(myIndex: number) {
    this.carrierSubject.next(myIndex);
  }
  setOrders(value) {
    console.log(value);
    this.orderSubject.next(value);
  }
  setTotalCost(value) {
    this.totalCostSubject.next(value);
  }
  lastSetTotalCost(value) {
    this.lastTotalCostSubject.next(value);
  }
}
```